# Node.JS with Express: Error : listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently trying to build a simple CRUD API using Node.js with Express. I usually have no trouble, but today, a new error message started to appear.

I can use a TCP Port once. If the server stops and restart, it gives me this error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 3111;

I can change the port, but can only use the new one once. The code giving me this is the following:

```js
// Load packages
const express = require("express");
const formidable = require("express-formidable");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");

// Initialize serve;
require("dotenv").config();
const mongoURL = process.env.DATABASE_URI;

const app = express();
app.use(formidable());
app.use(cors());

// Connect to the database
mongoose.connect(`${mongoURL}/Some_database`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Get all non-existent routes
app.all("*", (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).json({ message: "Ressource not found" });
});

// Launch server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server launched");
});
```

I launch the server using `npx nodemon index.js`.

I've already tried to get the process ID using the asked port with `sudo lsof -i tcp:3111`, as well as `killall -9 node`, but I don't get anything with these command, the last one only returns `No matching processes belonging to you were found`.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

EADDRINUSE means that the port number which listen() tries to bind the server to is already in use.

So, in your case, there must be running a server on port 3111 already.
search for process id:

```js
   sudo lsof -i :3111
```

this will list all the PIDs listening on this port, once you have the PID , you can terminate it with the following:

```js
kill -9 {PID}
```

restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thank you for the answer, Barrios. Sorry for this really delayed response.

I found the solution last week; for people who could get stuck with the same issue, I will start with answering the comments. First, I am working with MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3.

I tried the `sudo lsof -i :3111` before posting, but no server was found on this port, I couldn't find an ID to terminate with `kill -9` command.

Well, as often, the cause was very simple, I must have messed up when initializing my projet with `npm init -y` and no node_module repertory was created, each time I would launch my server, a hidden file would be created with the port number as its name and as long as it was there, I couldn't use the associated port.

Sorry for wasting time with this issue.